# SQL Server backup fails on disk space error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, backup

SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM running on Windows 2008 64bit.

Having problems backing up a single database with the following command

```
backup database [somedatabase] 
to disk = '\\somehost\d$\BACKUP\somedirectory\some_database.bak'
with compression, init, stats=1
```

The database backs up just fine for a while

```
93 percent processed.
94 percent processed.
```

Then I get an error about diskspace

> Msg 3202, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Write on "\somehost\d$\BACKUP\somedirectory\some_database.bak" failed: 1130 (Not enough server storage is available to process this command.)
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

This doesn't make any sense because there is over 800GB of available disk space and the backup is using 121GB.

In SQL Server's logs I get this message

```
Date        9/25/2013 1:04:56 PM
Log     SQL Server (Current - 9/25/2013 12:15:00 PM)

Source      Backup

Message
BackupIoRequest::ReportIoError: write failure on backup device 
'\\somehost\d$\BACKUP\somedirectory\some_database.bak'. Operating 
system error 1130(Not enough server storage is available to process
this command.).
```

**Some information:**

1. Backups are being executed from the server locally and the backup files are being saved to `\\somehost` which is another server close by.
2. Both the local and remote hosts have sufficient disk space.
3. Compression is on

Any assistance on getting to real cause of these backup failures would be appreciated.

Thank you

**Update 16:48**

As of R2, Compression is a backup option on standard. Thank you RLF. Still having the same problem with or without. The only difference is that the backup fails at 18% without compression. Decided to monitor disk space to make sure nothing else was eating up GB during the backup.

[image: Free space during backup]

As expected, available disk space went down to 600GB while using compression and 400GB without. Disk space never dipped below 400 though.

Comment: try backing up locally and then move the backup to a n/w location. See if that works. Also, the error is complaining about disk space.

Comment: @Kin Hello, yes I know its complaining about disk space, but there is plenty of it. I also just noticed that the backup systematically fails at 94%. Maybe CHECKDB will shed some light on this

Comment: You say "Compression is on".  Does that mean database backup compression? If so, good.  Or does that mean file compression is turned on for the backup share?  If so, then that is likely the problem. (From experience.)

Comment: @RLF I mean that the compression option was added. Now I realize that this is a standard edition and choosing compression as a backup option shouldn't even work.  Still, why would it fail after 94%?

Comment: You are running SQL Server 2008 R2, which can do compression on Standard Edition just fine.  As others have pointed out, the error is clear, the reason for the error is unclear.  Possibilities (1)  there is a storage problem or a network problem that kills the backup, (2) someone else is doing something that eats up storage and perhaps both fail,(3) the target share is using Windows compression and therefore reports an 'estimated size' that may not actually reflect how much data can be stored. (Or one of the things I did not think of.)

Comment: Is the share you're backing up to SAN storage or direct attached to the other host?  If it's SAN, it could be thinly provisioned, which could create your error.

Comment: @MikeFal - almost but no cigar :( I remember having that same problem at my last job, but in this situation that is not the issue. The two disk drives belong entirely to the server in question.

Comment: Is there anything in the event logs of the server you are backing up to?

Comment: What's the file system on the target?

Comment: Have you run `chkdsk` on the target volume?

Comment: How large is an uncompressed backup for the database?

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2 **RTM** ?  There are no service packs or cumulative updates applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error `not enough server storage available` is misleading.  This is not disk space, but Windows SMB management memory.  Try restarting the target machine (where the backup is being saved), or at least restart the Server service.

See the following Microsoft support link for instructions on potential registry changes that may be necessary at the machine where the backup is being stored.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304101

Also, you might try a search for "Windows Server error 1130" for more info.

Comment: Hello Max, I will try out restarting the server service and get back to you shortly.

Comment: Attempting restart of the server. Restarting the server service did not resolve the issue.

Comment: Following the recommendations from the KB link worked. Thank you Max for your help.